# Check file type in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I want to check certain files and see if their types and extensions are matching. What I'm currently doing is using the **file** command to check the mime type (or basic output from **file**) and comparing it with the file extension. However, some file types returns the same mime-type, **.sfx** and **.dll** for example.

Also i have some files with **no extension** at all, and i should be able to determine file type of them correctly.

I want to be able to get all file types correctly but the most important file types that i m currently interested in are;

- dll
- msi
- com
- cpl
- exe
- ocx
- tmp
- upd

Is there any other tool that checks and returns a file's type?

**EDIT**

I wrote a nodejs script that can be used as a linux command. I have created my own  file signature database by merging public databases, which has the following format for each file extension;

```
"ISO" : [
    {
        "signature": "4344303031", // byte sequence
        "size": 5, // size of byte sequence
        "offset": 32769 // offset in the file for the signature bytes
    },
    {
        "signature": "4344303031",
        "size": 5,
        "offset": 34817
    },
    {
        "signature": "4344303031",
        "size": 5,
        "offset": 36865
    }
]
```

Now; i first check signature bytes for the extension available in the file's name (text.iso will result .iso), and i go and check the signature bytes of that file to see if that is really an iso file.If it is indeed iso, i return iso as result.

If it's not iso, i check all the signature byte sequences for every extension i have in my db against the given file to see if any of them matches. If i have a match, i return the result.

If i cannot find a match, i execute the **file** command, get the file's mime-type, and use another db i created for matching mime-types with extensions, to see if that has a match. The format for the mime-type db is like this;

```
"application/atom+xml": [
    "atom",
    "xml"
],
"application/atomcat+xml": [
    "atomcat"
],
"application/atomsvc+xml": [
    "atomsvc"
]
```

This solution currently meets my project's needs. Maybe this might help someone else aswell.

Comment: You can only use file extension as a *hint*, the file-name extension doesn't have to be correct. Besides, there are only so many three-letter combinations available, many have to be reused for different types of files. Or how about the extension `.dat`? That is a *very* common extension for all kind of data files, few which are similar.

Comment: As for the files you list, those should have pretty unique signatures. The few first bytes of those types should be quite unique.

Comment: That is exactly why i'm trying to determine the file type; to not trust the file extension itself.

Comment: You are in the right direction. Most of the list of file types you have is pretty much known. For those that `file` can't tell apart, you can update/add into `/etc/magic` the signatures/headers of the file types of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python after `pip install filemagic`:

```
>>> import magic
>>> with magic.Magic() as m: m.id_filename('tmp.py')
... 
'Python script, ASCII text executable'
>>> with magic.Magic() as m: m.id_filename('test.html')
... 
'HTML document, ASCII text'
```

Comment: I now see that both python `magic` and `file` uses `libmagic`, so there shouldn't be differences. Now I am confused about the question as python magic reports differently for DLL and EXE on my system: 'PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows' and 'PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows', - but `file` also reports these differences.

Answer (score -1):

Linux has a built-in `file` command: [man file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file)

The main difference between Windows and *nix is that DOS/Windows has *built-in* dependencies on file suffix.  For example, an executable *must* be named ".exe" (or .com); a .bat file *must* be named ".bat" (or .cmd).

Linux, MacOS, BSD, etc have no such restriction.  Instead, they must have "execute" permission set in order to be "runable".  This is true for either a binary executable (e.g. compiled code) or a script (e.g. Python, Perl ... or a shell script).

Instead of relying only on file suffix, the "file" command also looks at self-identifying "magic numbers" or other "header information" in the file itself.

SUGGESTION:

If the built-in "file" doesn't meet your needs; perhaps you can wrap it in a shell script that:

1) Checks for certain "well known suffixes" (use [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) to extract the suffix), and/or

2) Calls "file" as a fallback

Comment: The OP mentioned the `file` command in the first paragraph of the question.